# LocalDate - parsing is case sensitive

Tags: java, java-8, java-time, date-parsing, localdate

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(isDateOdd("MAY 1 2013"));
    }

    public static boolean isDateOdd(String date) {

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd yyyy");
        formatter = formatter.withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); 
        LocalDate outputDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        return ((outputDate.getDayOfYear()%2!=0)?true:false);
    }
}
```

I want to know, if number of days, that passed from beginning of the year to some date is odd. I try to use LocalDate to parse date from my string (`MAY 1 2013`), but I get error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'MAY 1 2013' could not be parsed at index 0
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
> at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1851)
> at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400)
> at com.javarush.task.task08.task0827.Solution.isDateOdd(Solution.java:23)
> at com.javarush.task.task08.task0827.Solution.main(Solution.java:16)

Where's a problem?

Comment: how about `MAY 01 2013`?

Comment: Tried this just right now, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: MAY should be May also @nullpointer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use the month's input with all the capital letters, ex.`MAY`, you have to use the case-insensitive DateTimeFormatter:

```
public static boolean isDateOdd(String date) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .parseCaseInsensitive()
            .appendPattern("MMM d yyyy")
            .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
    LocalDate outputDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    return (outputDate.getDayOfYear() % 2 != 0);
}
```

As the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseCaseSensitive--) of the `parseCaseSensitive()` method says:

> Since the default is case sensitive, this method should only be used after a previous call to #parseCaseInsensitive.

Comment: Yes! Problem was in parseCaseInsensitive. Thank you. So, without .parseCaseIntensitive, it will work only with "May 01 1998", won't it?

Comment: Case insensitivity means the processing is not influenced with the leter casing. So all of the case-variations of the month will work: `mAy`, `MAY`, `may`, `mAY` etc...

Comment: @Aldres, you are correct, with the default case-sensitive parsing only May (capital M, small ay) will be recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Amend `MAY` to `May`, and `1` to `01` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Your day part should have two digits, i.e `"MAY 01 2013"` .

Then if you really want to pass upper-case month names, you should use a builder along with `parseCaseInsensitive()` .

Putting it all together :

```
public static boolean isDateOdd(String date) {

    DateTimeFormatterBuilder builder = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder();
    builder.parseCaseInsensitive();
    builder.appendPattern("MMM dd yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = builder.toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH); 

    LocalDate outputDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
    return ((outputDate.getDayOfYear()%2!=0)?true:false);
 }
}
```